# <pre><code> will not display the page - will not let me see the page

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

it is such that I would have liked to so that you can know code on the page. when I just is pure html in between `<pre>` and `<code>` so it works just fine with no problems,

but if I lie css, php, jquery, javascript into so it seems not at all in some manner.

When I lie in the code do I like this

```
<pre>
<code>
//code her
</code>
</pre>
```

when it comes out of the database looks like this;

```
<p>&lt;pre&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;code&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;?php echo \"hello\";?&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;/code&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;/pre&gt;</p>
```

I have [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) as text pluing so no matter what I do and it produces

when I make a new line!, and also make \ although I have not written it in the code.

The problem: this is so that must have shown my php code or the like then I do not see the page in some manner.

TinyMCE have i add its here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/artikler/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"
    });
</script>
```

*What should I write for a different version or a different theme?*

Comment: you could try  entity_encoding: "raw",

Answer (score 1):

Your problems is most likely that TinyMCE escapes all HTML tags.  To allow code to be embedded without adding the security risk of allowing other HTML tags to be inserted, I think this is what you want: https://code.google.com/p/tinymce-pre-plugin/

Comment: Hey, a is such that I can look at my javascript code to the theme "Simple" and that makes I can not do as will be shown in the video :( - what should I write in the present simple?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what problem you have using the plugin.  Can you explain a little more?